# Howto Copy string from textbox1, and use in subproccess command, and output in textbox2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Hi i wanna know how i can type a string "word" in textbox_1 (Top one box)
then copy that string and use in a subprocess command and output it into the textbox_2 (buttom box)without using signals

i try to copy the textbox_1, but that dosent seems to work.

my code looks as following.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(840, 460)
        self.textEdit_1 = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 291, 141))
        self.textEdit_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_1"))
        self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 301, 101))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_2"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 40, 381, 241))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "go", None))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        ff = self.textEdit_1.copy()
        dog1 = subprocess.Popen('help ' + ff, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        self.textEdit_2.setText(dog1.stdout.read())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```

using just one subprocess command without copy from text_box1 offcause output right text.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(840, 460)
        self.textEdit_1 = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 291, 141))
        self.textEdit_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_1"))
        self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 200, 301, 101))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_2"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 40, 381, 241))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "go", None))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        #ff = self.textEdit_1.copy()
        dog1 = subprocess.Popen('help start', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        self.textEdit_2.setText(dog1.stdout.read())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? "Copy" copies any selected text to the clipboard. You just type something in the box, then highlight some characters or the whole thing and hit "Run". Now you can paste it from the clipboard anywhere. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextedit.html#copy

Comment: no thats not what i mean.


If you look at the code, you see that im trying to use the text from textbox_1, and add that to my subprocess command "HELP" .
so if i type "START" in textbox_1, the output in textbox_2 would be "help START"

Comment: I don't know what you mean but your code copies the stuff to the clipboard just fine. You probably meant ff = self.textEdit_1.toPlainText()

Comment: maybe we are talking of defferent things here.

i wanna copy from to clipboard, from textbox_1.
then in my subprocess command, i allready have half the command "HELP"

dog1 = subprocess.Popen('HELP ' + ff, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).

I wanna paste the clipboard to rest of the command to ff.

Comment: EDIT!! i made a code error  ff = self.textEdit_1.toPlainText() works thx mate

Comment: OK. You copied the thing from form to clipboard, now you have to paste it from clipboard to subprocess, I guess. I'll put some code below.